# What would be the most efficient way for vampires to farm human blood?

Tags: magic, humans, vampires, farming

A bit of background to the question. Vampires are rare in human kingdoms and are hunted down, and the technology level across the world is around the 17th century level in terms of our world, since magic stunted scientific development.

Vampires need blood because human blood contains complex chemicals called succulents which attract and hold natural mana present in the atmosphere. They cannot make them by themselves. Vampires are composed of part flesh part magic, making them more adept at doing magic and also making them faster, stronger and more durable, basically magic holds them together like glue, if they don't get the succulents the need, they'll fall apart like legos. (Note: they don't burn in sunlight, don't know if this is useful or not however)

So back to the question, there's this kingdom of purely vampire citizens, and each one needs atleast 1 liters of human blood (per month) to not die. How would they be able to farm blood at such a large scale? (note: the number of vampires in the kingdom is around 2 million, humans in captivity are around 10-ish million)

Edit: Changed the two litres to one liter, per month (I forgot to write 'per how much time') and there are more humans now (at a ratio of 2:10).

Seems the question has been closed because I haven't given enough detail or clarity. I don't really know *what* detail to give, but I'll give anything that's important:

The kingdom can either breed humans, or, they can use their military might to force nearby human kingdoms to forfeit thousands of citizens in return for the kingdom not getting absolutely rampaged. Space and time magic do exist, but how to perform them have been lost to time, so that's a no-go.

My question is really just asking about how vampires can harvest human blood at such a scale, and how and where would these captive humans be kept, when there's 10 damn million of them. Are they in giant fortresses? Or are in villages where they would be forced to work the land, give food to their overlords and also keep some for their own sustenance, along with a tax of blood. How efficient would that system really be? How can it be improved?

Comment: They need two liters of blood *over what time*? Two liters of blood over 10 years is easy, you could even get humans to volunteer to donate or sell that. (A healthy adult male can donate about 3 liters of blood per year with no effect on his health.) Two liters of blood per day is very much harder to get.

Comment: Please remember that we’re not a brainstorming site. Asking us questions with many valid answers is not permitted on this site.

Comment: I'm presuming 2 litres of Blood is per day. Which would track with a Human-esque calorific requirement. Next question - does your Vampire world have human Familiars?

Comment: That ratio of captive humans to vampires is not the slightest bit sustainable. Humans generate 1 liter of blood every 24 days, so you need 48 humans for every vampire, at minimum. Probably even more than that since that's just the replacement rate. The Red Cross only allows about 1/2 liter to be donated every 56 days, so you really need a ratio closer to 1:224

Comment: I think the "per what unit of time" question actually doesn't need to be answered, instead it would be best to just drop the "2 liters" requirement altogether. The question states that the vampires require around half as many humans as there are vampires, at a minimum. If we want to get more specific, it could be possible to pair the vampire:human ratio to the quality of life for humans--if you say humans will be drained to an unhealthy extent at a 2:1 vampire:human ratio, but will be healthy at a 3:2 ratio, then that's the rule of your universe.

Comment: Consider also that there are different types of blood cells, and you can donate those at different rates, and that we don't know which cells catch mana or contain "succulents" (or maybe succulents are a new type of cell which are produced at some given rate). So even if you defined the fluff around the 2 liters really well, there would still be questions and quibbles there.

Comment: @Beefster: That's the replacement rate for blood plasma. The half-a-liter-every-two-months rule is based on the replacement rate for the red cells, which are replenished much slower than plasma. Long story short, if you take one liter of blood out of a human every 24 days the human will die on anemia.

Comment: @AlexP the liter-per-24-days figure is based on the figure that all 5L of your blood cells get replaced every 120 days, but I imagine that rate is helped by your body recycling old blood cells into new blood cells. The 1/2 liter every 8 weeks figure is based on how often you're allowed to donate blood, so I'm under the impression that doing so is safe and sustainable.

Comment: What is the technology level, 2 liters a day with modern tech is a triviality, 2 liters with medieval tech would have a huge body count. but no matter what tech you need a lot more humans than vampires. trophic levels don't allow much leeway.

Comment: The rate - and method - of blood consumption is vitally important for this question to be answerable.  Please [edit] the question to provide these details.

Comment: I think we've really over-focused on the 2 liters thing and brought in a lot of assumptions about the amount of blood that these vampires will need. There's no indication in the question that the vampires use blood for calories, they use it to get mana, a magical resource which can be present in the blood in whatever density the asker wants. It is fair to object that there are some little details that need to be provided, but we should also not add in our own details--all this stuff about blood donation and real world dietary requirements is us finding way to make the question harder.

Comment: With your edits you're asking a lot of questions at once. We have a strict one question per post policy on this site.

Comment: Unfortunately question is closed so I can't answer. But this has been done by many societies already. They keep the humans as slaves who breed more and eat some every now and then.  It not only gives you free workers, but keeps them in a state of terror.

Comment: Note--changing the ratio of vampires to humans from 2:1 to 1:2 invalidated my answer. Changes to questions that invalidate answers are generally frowned upon on these sites. Anyway, not writing to try and convince your to switch it back or anything; you are new, and I think you got an unexpected amount of pushback on this question! In particular, some folks seem to have decided to resolve the "2 liter per what" ambiguity in a direction that made your first ratio impossible (which was wrong of them to do), causing you to change it. Just a note for the future, edits should clarify not change.

Comment: @Zwuwdz thanks for the help

Comment: Some have said: 'what if succulents are some unique cell and have different replacement times?'. This is a non-issue, as the blood still has to be REMOVED to get the succulents, and filtering out red blood cells and putting them BACK IN THE HUMAN is impossible unless you contrived magic spells or impossible technologies to do it. As such, a 10-12 week interval is STILL THE ONLY WAY, as otherwise red blood cells would diminish until the humans died.

Comment: So, the blood extraction process is obvious and ordinary, and the consumption process is obvious to anyone who has ever heard of a vampire. (i.e. periodic bloodletting, vampires drink da blood, not very complex). The question itself is basically: 
'Would the most effective blood-farming method involve total imprisonment (in a dungeon), or some level of freedom and agency (in a controlled settlement), or some other system?'
(This is the implied question, I think??)
So really, I think this question should be opened, especially since the original closing reasons have been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

#### Quick Math

Today, people can generally donate 0.5 l of blood every 56 days.

This means, that per annum, a singular average adult human donor can contribute about 3.5 liters safely. Now, granted that this is aligned with modern health and safety guidelines, so you could probably squeeze more out of them, especially if you tailor the diets of your donors towards blood-production, but still. Not a lot. To supply the 12 l a single vampire needs, **you'd need between 3 and 4 healthy adult humans**. The problem is that not all humans are the same.

For example, a short adult woman can sustain significantly lower blood production than a large adult male. Similarly, if you want these healthy adult donors, then you need to have healthy children that grow up into healthy adults. Especially with how "pyramid-shaped" demographic curves used to be historically, this means that you'd need even more people on a per-vampire basis.

With infant mortality, larger families, lower life expectancy, and the adults constantly donating blood, it is not unreasonable to say that about half the population would be under 18 years old, so **the total number of humans required to sustain one vampire would probably be between 6 to 8 people.**

This means that in order to get 2 million vampires fed, you'd need another 8 million or so humans who need to supply blood, create progeny, and feed themselves. With how little caloric surplus was available at the time with agricultural techniques of the time, you'd probably need to increase the human pop. even further to support people when they're weakened after giving blood, so maybe stack on another couple million humans.

Also, this isn't considering that some vampire aristocracy might want more than 12 l per year, because they feel like extravagantly bathing in a bathtub of blood for kicks. Consider how many people are employed by the "luxury goods" sector, even historically (pearl divers, gemstone miners, gold, etc) and you can again slap another couple million to build up a bit of a surplus.

#### Making it work

With your vampires requiring this much blood, the most attractive option I see is simply running an empire. The largest empires of the 17th century were those in Asia with the Qing Dynasty at approx 100m or, a bit smaller, the Ottomans at maybe 30m. Your vampires simply form their own kingdom where they are the aristocracy, and instead of taxes, the peasantry simply tithe blood to their local landlords.

In order to prevent blood-logistics issues, you'd distribute the vampires.

For example, a small farming hamlet of 100 inhabitants might have a single family of four or five vampires acting as their local lords. The peasantry farms and provides with blood, and in return, the vampires act as local law enforcement, protection, and maybe lend their magical aid to make the people and fields fertile.

In general, the best way to play this situation from the perspective of the vampires is probably to get the humans on their side. Offer tangible benefits like protection (bye-bye local bandits) and healing magic (reduced infant and mother mortality) alongside perhaps painting the vampires as rightful religion-supported rulers and presto: the deal is so sweet that your human peasantry is even willing to fight against foreign human invaders when necessary because they think they've got a sweet deal (giving a pint of blood every two months isn't so bad).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps and an addendum to any other answer here: Afflict your "donors" with [Polycythemia vera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycythemia_vera)

> In oncology, polycythemia vera is an uncommon myeloproliferative
> neoplasm (chronic leukemia) in which the bone marrow makes too many
> red blood cells[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycythemia_vera) as well as white blood cells and platelets.

How you afflict them, and if the thicker blood is of benefit to the vampires is another question and up to the OP :)

Answer (score 0):

*Note for context: this answer applied when OP had the ratio of 2 vampires to 1 human and a need of 2 liters of blood (originally no timeframe on this, so I assumed per day)*

### You need *a lot* of willing or captive humans

Humans can only sustainably generate so much blood, specifically 1 liter every 24 days. That's the base replacement rate. If you could somehow capture all of (and only) the old blood cells that each human body would have recycled, you are left with a *minimum* vampire:human ratio of 1:48. That's assuming such a process is even possible.

More realistically, the safe maximum blood donation rate is 1/2 liter every 56 days. Maybe you can fudge that a little to 1/2 liter per 50 days, leaving you with a likely sustainable ratio of 200 humans per vampire. And maybe you can fudge that a little further with a special diet and magical supplements that increase the rate of blood replenishment. Maybe you can get down to 42-45 days.

### Time-dilation chamber?

If time magic is possible, you may be able to make due with your 2:1 vampire:human ratio by placing your humans in a chamber where time passes one year on the inside for each day on the outside. But that runs into more issues because now you have to deal with the fact that they age 365x faster as well, and therefore die every 60-75 days. Plus you'd have to drain each human once every few hours (according to the clock outside the chamber), ensure they keep breeding, etc...

That might be possible, but it has the same nutritional requirements of a massive farm of 3.65 billion humans. That's almost certainly not possible at 17th century technological levels, even with magic.

### Workarounds

Consider the following:

- Make your vampires *a lot* less thirsty
- Have some sort of nutritional supplement that sends human blood production into overdrive
- A reliable way to synthesize blood with alchemy, perhaps one that uses real blood as a seed or catalyst.
- Have a lot fewer vampires

Comment: Also a workaround - have a lot less vampires.

Comment: You can get an extra 5 liters when the "donor" expires. Depending on your pool this may be not insignificant.

Comment: @Gillgamesh if a person can donate 0.5 L per 50 days, then 5L at death equates to roughly 1.5 years of "normal" adult production.  Given how long it takes humans to mature, the vampires are better off keeping them alive as long as possible, at which point the death "extra" is a small percentage of the total from a given donor (victim).

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 i was only speaking of naturaly expiering donors, not prematurely killing off productive ones. And as I said depending on the pool you are drawing from..50? 50k?. How many expire in a given amount of time? 1.5y of production in 1 draw is significant.

Comment: Each vampire needs 12 liters/365 days, a year, please redo your math

Comment: Vampires need 12 l per year and humans can, assuming 0.5 l per 50 days, donate 3.65l per year. This means it takes about 3.3 donating humans to support one vampire. Where are you getting 200 from?

Comment: I don't follow the math - a vampire requires 1L/month, humans can safely donate 0.25L/month. It's a factor of 4x, not 200x.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie The math applied before OP changed the constraints of the question from 2 liters per some unknown period of time presumed to be a day to now being 1L/month

Comment: I've decided not to update my math and instead leave a note for context because the new blood needs completely change the answer and I want to keep the old one for posterity and reality-checking context.

Answer (score -1):

The numbers here need to be reversed.  You can't farm an animal less numerous than your own species and expect everyone to eat.  In our own world, humans account for about 36% of the mammal population, while livestock accounts for 60%, and meat only makes up a small portion of our very varied diet.  Imagine how much worse it would be if we were obligate carnivores who could only derive nutrients from one part of one slow growing species that they don't even produce that much of?  Vampires are solitary apex predators, and, as such, have nutrient requirements that stand at odds with large populations.  There aren't that many tigers because each tiger needs a lot of space with a lot of prey roaming around to support itself.  Vampires would likely work the same way.  Even getting them into a position where they could form cities would be a challenge, and would require massive captive human populations.  Vampires would need to be the minority even in their own cities, with at least 2 or 3 captive humans to every vampire.  This isn't all that unusual.  There were more slaves than citizens in the Roman Empire.  Historically, minority populations lording over much larger majorities has been a thing we have seen often.  Those recognized as citizens by a given society have often not been the most common people in that society.  A nation of vampires, likewise, need not have a majority vampire population.